# Как реализовать загрузку fancybox через несколько секунд после открытия страницы?

Tags: fancybox, popup

Приветствую.
Как заставить появляться на странице сайта окно fancybox через определенное время после открытия страницы?
Как управлять количеством открытий такого окна для посетителя?

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.funcybox('content');
  // или $('.open_fancy').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Количество кликов пиши в куку.